# Call exec inside a function - NameError

Tags: python

Why does this code raise `NameError`?:

```
def func():
    exec("my_var = 42")
    print(my_var)
func()
```

There are many related questions, but I have not found a clear answer as to WHY. I don't want a workaround.

Also, I have noticed that the code works when I run:

```
exec("my_var = 42", globals(), globals())
```

But not really sure why.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) for *exec()* states: "...if the optional parts are omitted [second and third arguments], the code is executed in the current scope.". The current scope is the *func()* function. Why can't I access *my_var* from this same scope?

Answer (score 4):

The parser/compiler doesn't take the argument to `exec()` into account (since it could be a variable). So when it parses the function it doesn't see the assignment to `my_var`, so it treats it as a global variable. But the assignment in `exec()` will create a local variable. So the variable that was assigned is not the same one that it tries to print.

In addition, if you want changes to local variables to be visible, you have to pass the `locals()` dictionary explicitly. The [documentation] states:

> **Note:** The default *locals* act as described for function [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) below: modifications to the default *locals* dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function `exec()` returns.

Comment: If the variable is in `locals()`, why `print()` doesn't check if the variable is in locals too? When running `print(locals())` the variable is inside.

Comment: Because the variable is a global variable, since there's no assignment to it anywhere in the function. So it looks for it in `globals()`.

Comment: @Cardstdani locals as in variables that exec() treats as local, not the function in which exec is called

Comment: The parser determines whether a variable is local or global at compile time, it's not a dynamic search at run time.

Comment: Took me a while to understand what you mean (I am still not sure). So from my interpretation of your answer, adding a `my_var = 0` before the `exec()` should print 42 and not 0. But try it out, it prints 0 so `my_var` is not updated. Why is this?

Comment: From the documentation: **modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns.**